Possibly Japanese foreign horror film with a mother and child in a new building
I would really like to find out the name of this movie I watched a while back so I can watch it again. I think it's from the late 90's or for sure the 2000s. It's not The Others or One Missed Call.
It starts with a woman and her son or daughter moving into a new building, and she begins to notice that strange things are happening. It turns out someone is living within the walls of the building. Some part in the movie goes to a flashback of a family and their house gets burned leaving their child behind or their whole city gets burned, I can't exactly remember what happens. Pretty terrifying movie though.

Approximate year of release? And do you remember anything else?

This sounds similar to "The Others" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Others_(2001_film) - but there was no burning involved IIRC.

I am not quite sure, I think it could have been late 90's or for sure in 2000 something

It is not the others, this was a Woman with 1 child and they lived in a apartment building

Was there a scabby-looking older woman involved?

Quite possibly I cannot remember, any movie names would help, I really want to watch it again cause it was genuinely horrifying, I thought it was One missed call but I was mistaken

OK, not 100% sure but I might have a match. I'll put it up.

This sounds like the 2005 Hong Kong horror film Gwai muk (The Monster AKA Home Sweet Home). It's about a mother, father and small son, but the father is incapacitated at some point and the movie focuses on the mother. They move to a new building and realize there's someone living in the walls, who takes their son. Turns out it's a woman who lost her husband in a fire and consequently her son when they were squatters in the same area. Here's the trailer:




Thank you very much, I've been trying to find this movie forever, I really appreciate it.
